# Unable to click on the link using selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

[Image Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX2lV.png) I want to click on the specific button on a webpage, using selenium webdriver and Python. Tried finding the element by CSS, class name and XPath, but it doesn't seem to work. I have attached an image showing the button I want to click (It is not a dropdown as the image suggests) and the HTML details. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you able to locate the element but not click it? Or you are not even able to locate it?

Comment: I am unable to locate the element.

Answer (score 0):

Actually sometimes selenium is not able to interact with some web elements using click try simulating enter key press on that element for e.g. -

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("value")
element.send_keys(:return)
```

Let me know if that works

Comment: Is that item visible? What xpath are you using? If you're using Firebug for finding xpath then paste your xpath in firebug and see if it marks that element on the screen with blue dotted lines if it does not, that means the element is there but can't be interacted with